# How to sign up to collect donations through Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm trying to sign up my charity to use the new Facebook donations tool, [recently made available in the UK](https://www.theguardian.com/voluntary-sector-network/2017/sep/12/facebook-donate-buttons-uk-charities).

All roads lead [to this page](https://www.facebook.com/donate/signup), which to me looks like this:

[image]

The crucial words are "To start your application, click the downward arrow next to your nonprofit or charity organization page from the list of pages below."

But there is no "list of pages below". I've clicked every downward arrow I can see on my charity's page. All help resources, including the "Click here for direct support" lead back to this page.

Can anyone help me to start an application for this service?